# INSERT UNION POC results into tel

Tags: t-sql, union

I would like to ALTER a proc so I can insert results into table. Can you please guide? thank you..

```
   ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_CtotalPPPP]
   AS
   BEGIN 
   SELECT   CID, Consumer1, Consumer2, datepart(year, getdate()) Year, 'Jan'  Month, [Jan_S] Budget, [JanAct] Act, getdate() 
         FROM            CProgramDetails
   UNION
   SELECT   CID, Consumer1, Consumer2, datepart(year, getdate()) Year, 'Feb' Month, [FEBOCV_Spend] Budget, [FEBAct] Act, getdate() 
        FROM            CProgramDetails
   UNION
   SELECT CID, Consumer1, Consumer2, date part(year, getdate()) Year, 'Mar' Month, [MarOCV_Spend] Budget, [MarAct] Act, getdate() 
        FROM            CProgramDetails
 UNION
 SELECT  CID, Consumer1, Consumer2, datepart(year, getdate()) Year, 'Apr' Month, [AprOCV_Spend] Budget, [AprAct] Act, getdate() 
        FROM            CProgramDetails
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ABCD123] (---this is failing - I do not know where to add this)

End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF [dbo].[ABCD123] already exists

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ABCD123]
Select ...
Union
Select ...
```

IF [dbo].[ABCD123] does NOT exist and you want to create it on-the-fly

```
SELECT   CID
       , Consumer1
       , Consumer2
       , datepart(year, getdate()) Year
       , 'Jan'  Month
       , [Jan_S] Budget
       , [JanAct] Act
       , getdate() 
 INTO  [dbo].[ABCD123]       --<< only once in the top query
 FROM   CProgramDetails
UNION
SELECT ...
UNION
SELECT
```

Comment: @ANASI-Newbie: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.